# Download Manager Android headers

Tags: android, kotlin

Я хочу скачать файл по ссылке. Но файл доступен только с определенного headers. Но я никак не найду в примерах и документации, чтобы такой параметр был.

headers такого вида `"Bearer" token`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov мне кажется вопрос был в том, как у Download Manager указать какой-либо headers

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request?hl=ru#addRequestHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) кажется, это то, что Вам нужно)